# Testdriven.io: Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker Error when trying to import app in conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, testdriven.io

I am following the testdriven.io  Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker tutorial and I am stuck on the Pytest setup step. I have checked over an over again to see what I am missing, and keep coming up short.

The code sample from the tutorial shows that, in conftest.py, you are to ahve the following `from` statement:

```
from app import main
from app.config import get_settings, Settings
```

For starters, Pycharm is telling me that it is unable to import anything from above.
My Folder Structure:
[image]

main.py:

```
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

from .config import get_settings, Settings

app = FastAPI()

register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
    modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
    generate_schemas=False,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)


@app.get("/ping")
async def pong(settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return {"ping": "pong", "environment": settings.environment, "testing": settings.testing}
```

conftest.py

```
import os

import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app import main
from app.config import get_settings, Settings


def get_settings_override():
    return Settings(testing=1, database_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_TEST_URL"))


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app():
    # set up
    main.app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override
    with TestClient(main.app) as test_client:
        # testing
        yield test_client

    # tear down
```

The tutorial has you run the tests using `docker-compose exec web python -m pytest`

This is the output I get when running the tests:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like this is entry level stuff that is causing an extreme headache.

Comment: It seems like you're running `pytest` on your whole code base (including libraries installed into your environment), and not just the `tests` directory. Try to invoke `python -m pytest tests` instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh, OK. That helped. The tests are running now, which is great.  It's still weird though that the imports aren't working right in the IDE... but it doesn't seem to matter when running the tests through docker? This also seems like a miss in the tutorial that the command to run the tests is wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because `app` isn't installed as a module - since `tests` has no way of importing `app` (except for the current directory being added to the sys.path), the import inside `conftest.py` doesn't really identify anything. The first tip in the pytest doc for good integration practices suggest installing your `app` module as an editable with `pip install -e`. I've usually done this myself, and it has worked fine (you'll need a setup.py file as shown in the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MatsLindh for the help. As he mentioned in his comments above, the tutorial has you running pytest on the entire project instead of just the tests folder. Running directly on tests solved my issue with pytest failing. He also gave good advice on getting imports to work correctly in an IDE by suggesting to look at the pytest documentation for further integration steps.